# Why these functions behavior differently

Tags: javascript, html, function, callback, dom-events

I'm trying to put an event listener on some buttons, however I can't understand how the parameters work in this context of callback.

Why this works?:

```
function modifyDisplay() {
    console.log(this.textContent)

}

buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    
    button.addEventListener("click", modifyDisplay)
})
```

And this doesn't:

```
function modifyDisplay(button) {
    console.log(button.textContent)

}

buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    
    button.addEventListener("click", modifyDisplay)
})
```

Comment: The parameter passed to a click callback is a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) object. You've misleadingly named it "button" in the second example, but it's an event.

Comment: You can call it (e) and do e.target.textContentt